# \rowcolor in \NewDocumentCommand

Tags: tables, color, xparse, colortbl

It seems to be impossible to wrap `\rowcolor` in a macro defined with `\NewDocumentCommand`, while everything is fine with `\newcommand`. Is ist possible to fixe this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\rowI}{}{
    \rowcolor{blue}
}
%\newcommand{\rowI}{
%   \rowcolor{green}
%}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
    \rowI 1 & 2 & 3 \\
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Since the error only appears with `\NewDocumentCommand` I guess `xparse` causes the problem and not `\rowcolor` itself …

Comment: macros defined with `\NewDocumentCommand` are e-TeX protected which I guess is the problem. Have you tried with `\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The definition of `\rowcolor` in `colortbl.sty` is

```
\def\rowcolor{%
  \noalign{\ifnum0=`}\fi
  \global\let\CT@do@color\CT@@do@color
  \@ifnextchar[\CT@rowa\CT@rowb}
```

Thus we see that it starts with `\noalign`. When TeX is doing an alignment (with the primitive `\halign`, as is the case with `tabular`), when it has scanned a `\cr` that ends a row (including the one generated by the table preamble) it expands the next token in order to see if `\omit` or `\noalign` comes along. This is how `\hline` the optional argument to `\\` or `\multicolumn` work. TeX continues expanding tokens until either it finds `\noalign`/`\omit` or another unexpandable token.

You have to know that `\NewDocumentCommand` uses the e-TeX feature called `\protected`; a macro defined with the `\protected` prefix will behave as if it were an unexpandable token as far as the scanning mechanism above is concerned: it will be considered equivalent to `\relax` for the time being, but it will be expanded normally after this preliminary lookup has ended.

(The same behavior happens for `\protected` macros in an `\edef`.)

So, *never* define with `\NewDocumentCommand` macros that contain (at the start of their replacement text) things that *must* be first in an alignment cell, such as `\multicolumn`, `\hline`, `\cline` (the same applies for the rule making commands of `booktabs`) or `\rowcolor` of `colortbl`.

The same limitation above applies for commands defined with `\newcommand` to have an optional argument, because they are expanded in a delayed fashion that would break the scanning for `\omit`/`\noalign`.

Use `\newcommand` (without optional arguments) or, if you really need an optional argument, `\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand` of `xparse` (but check the documentation for the limitations in this case, for instance you need a mandatory argument after an optional argument).

Comment: Thanks for your explanations, but doesn’t “_never_ define …” contradict “Use `\newcommand` …”. So what is _best practice_ for defining a command for my table headings and isn’t it _bad practice_ to mix up `\newcommand` and `\DeclareDocumentCommand` ins a `sty` file?

Comment: @Tobi You're right: some bits of the answer remained in my head.

Comment: Now it makes sense … but what is the/your advice? Stick to `xparse` and use `\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand` or mix “old” and “new“ syntax …

Comment: @Tobi It's not “old and new”. Use `\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand` (I hope it will be given a better name), if you want; or stick to `\newcommand`, which I hope will not be an alias of `\NewDocumentCommand` in view of these glitches. But LaTeX3 is still quite far away.

Comment: Thanks again. I know that it’s not really “old and new” :-)